# Avoid refresh of the fragments when switching between them

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I made an activity with a navigation bar, where I switch the content (fragments) by pressing on them. The problem is that every time I do it, I get the fragments refreshed, without being able to see the content before switching from them. This is my code:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        Fragment fragment;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bbn_item1:
                onResume();
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                }else {
                    fragment= new NetworkNotAvailable();
                }
                currentIndex=0;
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

                return true;
            case R.id.bbn_item2:
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                    fragment = new PopularFragment();
                }else {
                    fragment= new NetworkNotAvailable();
                }
                try{
                    if(currentIndex < 1 ){
                        FragmentTransaction transactionb = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_right,R.anim.push_out_left);
                        transactionb.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        transactionb.addToBackStack(null);
                        transactionb.commit();
                        currentIndex=1;

                    }else if (currentIndex > 1){
                        FragmentTransaction transactionb = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_left,R.anim.push_out_right);
                        transactionb.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        transactionb.addToBackStack(null);
                        transactionb.commit();
                        currentIndex=1;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return true;
            case R.id.bbn_item3:
                if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                    fragment = new PlayingFragment();
                }else {
                    fragment= new NetworkNotAvailable();
                }
                currentIndex=2;
                FragmentTransaction transactionc = getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.pull_in_right,R.anim.push_out_left);
                transactionc.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                transactionc.addToBackStack(null);
                transactionc.commit();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

In my activities I already implemented the onResume() method, but it looks like it gets invoked as soon as I open the fragment (it works as a onCreate())

Comment: Every time you switch the fragment, the frag get destroyed. You should use ViewModel to hold data of one or multiple fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by saving an instance of each fragment and passing it as parameter through the activity leacher instead of a generic "new Fragment()".